# How to read a symlink file in Java?

Tags: java, symlink

I want to read the contents of a symlink in Java *without* following the symlink. I know that there are many functions in `Files` that allow for the `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` option, including `Files.copy(symlinkpath, newsymlinkpath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)`, however, it looks like input streams like `FileInputStream` don't have this same option (it will try to follow symlinks by default).

It seems like it should be easy to read the byte representation of a symlink into a buffer in Java, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: ...why do you want the underlying representation?  The symlink only acts as a pointer to other files or folders and is largely abstracted out to that purpose.

Comment: I should be able to read the byte representation of the file I want without Java forcing me to follow it. Java is low-level enough to be able to allow that.

Comment: In any case, what prompted me to ask this is zipping files _including_ symlinks without following them. How would you copy a symlink to a `ZipOutputStream`? `Files.copy(Path source, OutputStream out)` doesn't support `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS`, so one seemingly obvious avenue is to read the symlink into a buffer and write it to the `ZipOutputStream` manually.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to zip a folder and preserve the pointers as opposed to zipping the folder and preserving the resolved data.  What have you tried to do so far to solve this?  I'd imagine that you're running into some kind of error or seeing some kind of behavior you find undesirable when you're evoking some specific call...

Comment: If you don't understand, please read up on zip. This question is about how to read a symlink without following it in Java.

Comment: I don't follow you here, and I'm an expert in Java who has created zip files before.  I also have extensive Linux expertise and know what symlinks are and what role they serve.  There is no *value* in reading a symlink without following it, so I'm trying to figure out what it is you're trying to really *accomplish* here.  Without clarity it becomes nigh impossible to answer your question, since this seems like an oddball circumstance.  Normally this isn't what you want to do.  Why do you want to do it?

Comment: *It seems like it should be easy to read the byte representation of a symlink into a buffer in Java, but I can't seem to figure it out.* The 'raw bytes' of a symlink would live outside userspace. You would be reading the raw file system, and, needless to say, different file systems would have different representations, but what would your [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)
be?

Comment: First, the raw bytes of a symlink aren't isolated from userspace. A symlink is just like a regular file, except that it has information that points it to another file @g00se. I'm not talking about a hard link. I would like to stick to the question that I have asked @Makoto. Symlinks are, at their core, regular files, and should be able to be read as such without following them. Plenty of people find value in zipping symlinks. That's why in a Linux shell, `zip -y` exists. I personally don't like zipping symlinks, but it's what the services I work on require.

Comment: *First, the raw bytes of a symlink aren't isolated from userspace.* I'm willing to take your word for it. Please demonstrate that with a bash command.

Comment: `readlink /etc/resolv.conf` outputs `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` on my system.

Comment: *readlink...* That's *not* reading the "raw bytes" of the link. That's showing the path of the target of the link (as indeed is the 'answer' below)

Comment: And said target is stored where? Inside the link. You're arguing semantics where there's nothing to argue about.

Comment: It's not semantics. The "raw bytes" of a link are a wholly different thing from the logical content of a link (the path to the target). Perhaps the OP should have asked "How do I get the target of a symlink without following it?"

Comment: I'm guessing your goal (which I shouldn't have to do) but if it's to place a working link into a compressed archive, then use tar, which supports links

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input. I definitely needed a refresher on filesystems. I will accept the current answer since the byte representation of a symbolic link can be interpreted as the equivalent of the byte representation of a regular file. Taking the ext4 filesystem as an example, the data for a regular file is stored in data blocks, and a symlink will store the target in data blocks if it is too long to be stored within `inode.i_block`. For a file to be considered a symbolic link, there is additional file metadata within the inode table that is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.nio.file.Files has [readSymbolicLink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path)) which does what you want.

> Reads the target of a symbolic link (optional operation).
>
> If the file system supports symbolic links then this method is used to read the target of the link, failing if the file is not a symbolic link. The target of the link need not exist. The returned Path object will be associated with the same file system as link.

Example:

```java
try {
    Path file = Files.readSymbolicLink(link);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Does it though?  This just reads like it resolves a path to the symlink, but doesn't present the byte structure that the OP is requiring.